# update query not working in mongoDB object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having below format document

```json
{
   "_id":"5f10481e74d83d4b726fdf33",
   "name":"1234",
   "settings":{
      "allowedUser":true,
      "theme":"lowergrade"
   }
}
```

I want to write update query for `settings.theme`, so I have written below mongo query

```js
db.test.update({
  _id: "5f10481e74d83d4b726fdf33"
},
{
  $set: {
    "settings": {
      "theme": "lowergrade123",
      
    }
  }
})
```

Update is happening proper but `"allowedUser" : true,` key and value was deleted.

This is my expected answer

```json
{
   "_id":"5f10481e74d83d4b726fdf33",
   "name":"1234",
   "settings":{
      "allowedUser":true,
      "theme":"lowergrade123"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.update({ _id: "5f10481e74d83d4b726fdf33" }, {
  $set: {
    "settings.theme":  "lowergrade123",
  }
})
```

You need to use `.` to set a value of a field. You are actually replacing `settings`.